# PostgreSQL updating many keys in jsonb field.

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer,
    data jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, data)
    VALUES (1, '{"user": {}, "survey": {}}');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, data)
    VALUES (2, '{"user": {}, "survey": {}}');
```

I want to update all records in `survey_results` table to have the following values in `data` column:

```
{"user":{"dob": '1995'},"survey":{"id": '1234'}}
```

How can I do that? I tried to do that with `jsonb_set` but I was not able to set all keys. Any ideas?

Here is sqlfiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i49SiaQn6qWcwiWDxVbHnn/8

Comment: this would be sooo easy with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you oversimplified your question, because with your sample data you can achieve what you want by simply overwriting the value in the column:

```
update survey_results
  set data = '{"user": {"dob": 1995}, "survey": {"id": 1234}}'::jsonb
```

If you want to preserve potential other keys in the JSON document, and only update those two key, you need to nest the `jsonb_set()` calls for each key you want to change:

```
update survey_results
  set data = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(data, '{user}', '{"dob": 1995}', true), '{survey}', '{"id": 1234}', true);
```